# Using r.js to optimize bower_components directly

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I'm having trouble using r.js to optimize modules in the `bower_components/` directory.

My basic project directory structure looks like this:

```
- bower_components/
- src/
  - activities/
  - client/
```

...and the r.js configuration lists the following details:

```
({
  appDir: 'src',
  baseUrl: 'client',
  dir: 'out',
  modules: [
    { name: 'scripts/main' },
    /* (+ more) */
  ]
})
```

I'd like to optimize the file
`bower_components/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io`, which is outside the
`baseUrl`. As recommended in [the "Common Pitfalls" section of the Optimizer
guide](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html#pitfalls), I'm trying to
define a path for the file:

```
 ({
   appDir: 'src',
   baseUrl: 'client',
   dir: 'out',
+  paths: {
+    'socket.io': '../../bower_components/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io'
+  },
   modules: [
     { name: 'scripts/main' },
     /* (+ more) */
+    { name: 'socket.io' }
   ]
 })
```

...but this yields the following error:

```
Running "requirejs:prod" (requirejs) task
{ [Error: Error: Module ID 'socket.io' has a source path that is same as output path: /home/mike/projects/cee/bower_components/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js. Stopping, config is malformed.
    at /home/mike/projects/cee/node_modules/grunt-contrib-requirejs/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:26000:39
]
  originalError: [Error: Module ID 'socket.io' has a source path that is same as output path: /home/mike/projects/cee/bower_components/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js. Stopping, config is malformed.] }
```

It seems like the point of the `path` config indirection is so that the
optimizer will not attempt to create a file outside the output directory. At
the same time, this is clearly not happening. Am I doing something wrong? Or is
this not something r.js is capable of?

Comment: Why would you want to use r.js on bower components? Imho bower components contain 3th party components (or in-house components) and should have a minified version too. It seems a strange idea to minify code you don't manage/develop.

Comment: One reason might be to build everything into one single file, instead of making the browser make many requests to get each component.